# How to create INSERT query that adds sequence number in one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `sample_1` in a **Postgres 10.7** database with some longitudinal research data and an ascending `sequence` number per `key`. I need to `INSERT` data from a staging table (`sample_2`) maintaining the `sequence` column accordingly.

`sequence` numbers are 0-based. I assume I need a query to seek the greatest `sequence` number per `key` in `sample_1` and add that to each new row's follow-up sequence number. I'm mainly struggling at this step with the sequence number arithmetic. Tried this:

```
INSERT INTO sample_1 (KEY, SEQUENCE, DATA)
SELECT KEY, sample_2.SEQUENCE + max(sample_1.SEQUENCE), DATA
FROM sample_2;
```

However, I get errors saying I can't use 'sample_1.SEQUENCE' in Line 2 because that's the table being inserted in to. I can't figure out how to do the arithmetic with my insert sequence!

Sample data:

```
sample_1

| KEY         | SEQUENCE | DATA |
+-------------+----------+------+
| YMH_0001_XX |     0    |  a   |
| YMH_0001_XX |     1    |  b   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     0    |  c   |
```

```
sample_2

| KEY         | SEQUENCE | DATA |
+-------------+----------+------+
| YMH_0001_XX |     1    |  d   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     1    |  e   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     2    |  f   |
```

I want to continue ascending `sequence` numbers per `key` for inserted rows.

To be clear, the resultant table in this example would be 3 columns and 6 rows as such:

```
sample_1

| KEY         | SEQUENCE | DATA |
+-------------+----------+------+
| YMH_0001_XX |     0    |  a   |
| YMH_0001_XX |     1    |  b   |
| YMH_0001_XX |     2    |  d   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     0    |  c   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     1    |  e   |
| YMH_0002_YY |     2    |  f   |
```

Comment: If you are adding `max(seq)` in `sample_1` to all the rows, shouldn't it  `sequence` of the last 2 rows in your resultant table be 2 and 3?

Comment: @Crazy2crack - I'm not sure I understand why? The only row in '1' for YMH_0002 is sequence == 0 so max(1.sequence) + 2.sequence equals 1 and 2 respectively?
Baseline is sequence for each individual's code is 0 and all subsequent timepoints are 1, 2, etc.

Comment: Ideally, you provide your version of Postgres and exact table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements clarifying data types, constraints, default values, ...) And also disclose any triggers, sequences etc. that may be involved.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thank you. I will edit my post. As this is my first post, it gave me a guided tour to generate it and specifically mentioned avoiding version numbers unless specifically required.

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify the description. Please edit if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do what you are after:

```
INSERT INTO sample_1 (key, sequence, data)
SELECT s2.key
     , COALESCE(s1.seq_base, -1)
     + row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s2.key ORDER BY s2.sequence)
     , s2.data
FROM   sample_2 s2
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT key, max(sequence) AS seq_base
   FROM   sample_1
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s1 USING (key);
```

Notes

- You need to build on the existing maximum `sequence` per `key` in `sample_1`. (I named it `seq_base`.) Compute that in a subquery and join to it.
- Add [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to it as demonstrated. That preserves the order of input rows, discarding absolute numbers.
- We need the ***`LEFT`***`JOIN` to avoid losing rows with new keys from `sample_2`.
  Likewise, we need `COALESCE` to start a fresh sequence for new keys. Default to *-1* to effectively start sequences with *0* after adding the 1-based row number.
- This is not safe for concurrent execution, but I don't think that's your use case.

Comment: Many thanks, Erwin! I think I can see how this would work - I'll have a look and see how I go.